# Has aynyone tried indexing a screwturn wiki, using Lucene-solr?

Tags: solr, wiki, screwturn

At our university they have chosen to implement screwturn wiki. I am responsible for the enterprise search solution at this organisation. This solution is based on Solr-Lucene. I have been looking around if people have tried to unlock the pages from this wiki or even better, have done so and indexed them using Lucene-solr. So far I have not found much.

Comment: What is so special with the wiki that you cannot use Nutch + solr?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the screwturn sitemap and feed it to SOLR:"http://www.tnrglobal.com/sys-admin-blog/category/solr/

Answer (score 0):

ScrewTurn Wiki v4 alpha uses Lucene.net for indexing. Lucene.NET is compatible with Lucene so you maybe able to get Solr to read these indexes also?  Unfortunately I don't know solr that well.